# Issues installing pymc3 on windows 64 bit Anaconda install

Tags: python, pymc3

I am trying to go through the Python for Finance book. I am on Chapter 11 - the part with Bayesian Statistics and it requires me to install pymc3 on my machine. For info I am running Win 7 with the latest version of Anaconda.

Anaconda comes with pymc v2.3.6. But the examples come with version 3. Anyway, I followed the documentation for pymc3 to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
cd pymc3
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This seemed to work. I now have pymc3 on my PC ... it is in `../../Github/pymc3` folder on my computer. The problem is I cannot seem to `import` it in Anaconda through Jupyter.

If I use `import pymc as pm` it still goes to the old version. If I say `import pymc3 as pm` then it doesn't recognise the module.

I suspect that Anaconda isn't picking up the pymc3 distribution. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: pip should install PyMC3 inside the Anaconda directory. 

Do you have the Anaconda version of pip? Try doing ```conda install pip``` and the installing PyMC3.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Did you try using `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3`?

Comment: if you're still stuck i had more luck installing on windows. here's my soln. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728877/using-pymc3-on-windows-10-theano-cannot-import-name-floatx?noredirect=1#comment72639271_42728877

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps in windows:

1. Run anaconda prompt as administrator (assume that you have anaconda)
2. Type `conda install m2w64-toolchain`

Just follow the steps and install will be finished.

Then,

3. type `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3`

your problem will be solved (hope so :) )

cheers!